# npm install fails with Permission denied (publickey). Could not read from remote repository

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, ssh

I have configured SSH key and added it to my GitHub account. 
Then I have cloned private repo with ssh, and tried to install node modules (some of them are private):

```
    "package1": "git+ssh://git@github.com:company/package1.git#0.0.2",
    "package2": "git+ssh://git@github.com:company/package2.git#1.1.1",
```

and it fails with

```
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks odd, but adding key to ssh-agent one more time helped:

```sh
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Anyway, how i could clone repo if key was not added to agent?